# Removing the last line of a text file, instead of appending one?

Tags: bash, append, line, echo

In my Bash script, I write lines to a text file.

```
echo "string" > /folder/file.txt
```

The above example creates a new file and writes the string to that file.

```
echo "string" >> /folder/file.txt
```

The second example appends to the file, writing the string on a new line.

My question is… Is there a single command to remove the last line? If not, I guess I'll have to copy line by line into a temporary file, stop before the last line which is the one I want to remove, and then overwrite the old file with the new one (now without the last line). If that is the only solution, is there a way to find out how many lines there are in a text file? So I can do a loop stopping at "n - 1".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU head:

```
$ head -n -1 file
```

prints all but the last (-1) line.

Comment: Thank you very much, works great for my needs. I'm printing it to a file using **head -n -1 fromfile > tofile**. Out of curiosity, what's the shortest way to make changes to the original file? Do I have to use **head** to a temporary file, then moving the temporary file overwriting the original one? Or perhaps there's a little… trick?

Answer (score 6):

```
{ echo 1; echo 2 ; echo 3 ; } | sed  '$d'
```

**output**

```
1
2
```

or with a file

```
 sed '$d' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

OR with newer seds

```
sed -i '$d' file
```

the `$` char is taken as a range-address value meaning 'last-line-in-file'. You'll also see `$` used in regular expressions like '/at end of Line$/' (note the reg-exp delimiter pair of '/.../'). When used in a reg expression, `$` now means 'end-of-line'

If you really want to know how many lines in a file (and assign it to a variable), do

```
lineCount=$(/bin/wc -l <file)

echo $lineCount
```

IHTH

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you might do it using `awk`:

```
$ seq 1 5 | awk 'NR>1{print l}{l=$0}'
1
2
3
4
```

Using `perl`:

```
$ seq 1 5 | perl -ne 'print if !eof'
1
2
3
4
```

Or if you prefer tic-tac-toe! (using `tac` and `sed`):

```
$ seq 1 5 | tac | sed '1d' | tac
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: oh come-on, I'm sure you know about `sed '$d'`. Why `tac+sed+tac`? :P